# OpenGL Camera/Projection

Tags: c++, opengl, projection, glm-math

I'm trying to implement a small rendering system using C++ and OpenGL. I've implemented one before but now I'm trying to change the structure behind it so I am starting fresh.

I'm already a little bit stuck,
because there is an error in the projection/camera, but I simply can't find it.
There is no movement in the Z direction and I think the clipping planes are messed up, because moving along the forward vector only manipulates the part that is rendered and not the distance to the objects (or the size of them).That's what led me to the idea that my projection is buggy.

That's how I set my matrices using glm.

```
m_view = glm::lookAt(m_pos, m_pos +  m_forward, m_up);
m_projection = glm::perspective(m_fov, (float)Engine::getInstance()->getWindowWidth()/(float)Engine::getInstance()->getWindowHeight(), 0.1f, 1000.0f);
```

And thats my vertex shader

```
#version 330 core


uniform mat4 model; 
uniform mat4 view; 
uniform mat4 projection;
varying vec4 worldPos;

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    worldPos =   projection*view *  model   * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(worldPos.x, worldPos.y, worldPos.z, 1.0);
}
```

And thats how I set the uniforms

```
 glUniformMatrix4fv(m_uniforms[VIEW_U],1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(view_matrix) );
```

And error is only thrown when initializing GLEW, but from what I've read that error can be ignored.

I know that this are only small code parts, but the entire code can be found in my github project.

https://github.com/pastad/PSEngine.git here the link to my project.
A part of the code I took from http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Camera in an attempt to eliminate potential error sources.

I know thats pretty basic stuff, but I can't find my mistake.
Thanks for your time!

The picture shows the current output. But there should be a number of small cubes
[image: should render whole cubes]

Answer (score 0):

The vertexshader was wrong. I calculated worldPos correctly and then converted it again to a vec4 with a w of 1.0 which caused the error.

```
    gl_Position =   projection*view *  model   * vec4(position, 1.0f);
```